# How to connect timeline in gsap react for different elements?

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I have 2 element i wanna animate in react with gsap time line.
The thing is when i wanna chain the time line. its giving me error

Something I want

```
gsap.to(element1, 1, {...}).to(element2, 1, {...}).to(element2,.5,{...})
```

But the above code is giving me errors.

So i am writing something like this

```
gsap.to(appBack.current, 1, {
      css: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
      },
    });
    gsap.to(overlay.current, 0.3, {
      css: {
        x: "-100vw",
      },
    });
    gsap.to(overlay.current, 0.3, {
      css: {
        opacity: 1,
      },
    });
```

This is not giving me error anymore but i don't want this kind of behaviour. Since this gsap timelines are happening at the same time

Comment: Check out [the most common GSAP mistakes](https://greensock.com/mistakes/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from the GSAP tutorial where green, orange and grey are classes, you can use also ids like #pink

Check the complete tutorial here https://greensock.com/get-started/

```
var tl = gsap.timeline({repeat: 30, repeatDelay: 1});

//add 3 tweens that will play in direct succession.
tl.to(".green", {duration: 1, x: 200});
tl.to(".orange", {duration: 1, x: 200, scale: 0.2});
tl.to(".grey", {duration: 1, x: 200, scale: 2, y: 20});
```

Comment: You don't need write `tl.to` every time you can write like `tl.to().to().fromTo()...`